# create workflow list with code

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, deployment, visual-studio-2013

I want to create a custom workflow for an existing list or library with code in visual studio and I do not want to do it on this way : [Create VS WorkFlow](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620173/Step-by-Step-Approach-to-Create-a-Visual-Studio-Sh)

I want to create the workflow from the beginning using code (to specify the stages) and then to publish it to SharePoint.

Comment: What do you mean "from the beginning"? be more clear, pls

Comment: all the steps that i use to do when i create a workflow in sharepoint designer i want to do it with visual studio :

Comment: And why the link that u provided is not right for u? It is from visual studio

Comment: because i don't want to use visual studio workflow designer i want to use code only

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to deploy a WorkFlow without using the design manager, is to deploy some **event receivers** and handle the items event.

[workflow or event receiver?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115104/which-one-is-better-considering-performance-workflow-or-event-receiver)

[How to: Create an Event Receiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ee231563.aspx)

[Table of SharePoint Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408183(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/05/managing-sharepoint-2013-workflows-with.html       this an association from an existing workflow definition . i want to create a custom workflow that is not related to another one